# Running Socket.IO Different Pages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have a problem with Socket.IO :

I want to use socket.io in two different pages (different scripts) , so i have to call "" two times . But the problem is when i call two times, only one client side works. Let me explain more the problem :

i have two different files which contain a call of `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` , the two client side of the socket work fine , but the problem is that when i try to make it work together only one of the client socket work , and i have to make it work simultaneously.

i have this code in the server side : `app1.io1.sockets.emit('socket_decompte', secondes , valeur.id );` and also : `app1.io1.sockets.emit('testsocket', result0[0].nbconnexion, result0[0].startdate, req.params.id, liste_con);` this two line of code are in the same route wich is product.js and in the client side i have two file index.ejs and product.ejs in this two file i call `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`. but when i call it in the two file just the code in index.ejs still work and no more in product.ejs

Do you have any solution so I can use Socket.IO on two different pages ?

Comment: this deserve an answer..running socket.io in different script, pose some problem

Comment: No answer for the moment, we are still trying to find a way..